# Dynamically change value of hidden field

Tags: c#, asp.net

For an existing site, I have to pass values in hidden fields from a form that's loaded by different pages (eg. City1.aspx, City2.aspx, City3.aspx, etc.), but they are loaded inside an iframe. I also have to dynamically change the value of at least one of those hidden field (let's call it "source") based on the city page loading it. I am familiar with PHP and JavaScript/JQuery, but I have no idea how to do this in C#.

I've found tutorials on retrieving the file name (sans extension) via JavaScript. I think I can still get the city even if the form is in an iframe, but I'd like to keep to the site's conventions and use C# if possible.

Code snippets or links to possible solutions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you need to change the value of the hidden field that is loaded in an iframe that is embedded in your .aspx file?  So you have no direct server side access to the hidden fields you need to change (if I'm understanding your question)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Any reason you can't use a hiddenfield control inside an updatepanel instead of the iframe?

Comment: Are the pages in the `iframe` coming from the the same domain? If not, you're going to hit "cross-domain policy" issues.

Comment: Coding Gorilla: I've been tasked with adding hidden fields to the form (done), now I just have to set values, except that the city is based on the page loading it.

Tim: I did not build this site, and the client wants to keep things the way they are - one generic form loaded by multiple pages assocaited with various office locations.

Freefaller: They're hosted on the same domain.

Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: This doesn't look like a C# issue. If you're trying to access/modify controls within an `iframe` from outside the `iframe` then that is client-side, and all down to javascript, which you say you're already familiar with.

Comment: Freefaller: Yep, I can do it that way, though I was hoping for a C#/asp solution. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry @John, I obviously don't understand the problem, as what you're trying to do has to happen on the client, therefore there *is* no solution available on the server-side. Yes, you might be able to create the solution using C#/ASP, but the end result must be a client side script. (On a side note, when [replying to comments in SO](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) you should put the `@` symbol before the username, otherwise they will not get a notification)

Comment: @John, are you able to update the `CityX.aspx` pages?

Comment: @freefaller : Good tip. I was wondering about that. But yes, you've understood it perfectly. It's a client side problem. Now I just have to figure out what to add to the corresponding .cs file to pass the contents. Thanks again. ... Yes, I can edit the aspx pages. Doing that to the form right now.

Comment: Please see "[Stack Overflow does not allow tags in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208)".

Answer (score 2):

if you want modify the value of your input in c# associated to your aspx (Code behind), you must to add attributes runat=server to your input.

use this code in your aspx

```
<input id="test" type="hidden" runat="server"/>
```

and in your c#

```
test.Value = 123; //your value is 123 for example
```

Comment: I'm not familiar at all with "runat", but this gives me something good to work on. Thanks much!

Comment: I'am happy to unlock your problem

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer, I don't know JQuery, so there could be easier ways to do this.  I also haven't tested any code...

If you know the exact ID then you can do something like this from the parent page (in a javascript block):

```
var frame = document.getElementById('myIFrame');
var ctrl = frame.document.getElementById('myControl');
ctrl.value = "New Value";
```

If you don't know the exact ID's of the controls in the `CityX.aspx` pages, then you will either need a way for those ID's to be discovered, or you will need to go through all controls within the `iframe` looking for the correct one.  (I say this because if the controls in the `iframe` pages are held in any sort of ASP.NET structure they will not be called `txtMyCtrl` (for instance) but possibly something like `ct00_txtMyCtrl`.)

If you don't know the EXACT control name (because of the ASP.NET structure I mentioned before), you could do something like:

```
var frame = document.getElementById('myIFrame');
var ctrls = frame.document.getElementByTagName("INPUT");
for(var i=0;i<ctrls.length;i++){
  if(ctrls[i].getAttribute("type")=="hidden" && ctrls[i].id.indexOf("_myControl") != -1){
    ctrls[i].value = "New Value";
    break;
  }
}
```

Or if you have the ability to update the `CityX.aspx` pages, then you could have the following in the `CityX.aspx` page:

```
function getCtrls(){
  return [document.getElementById("<%=hiddenCtrl.ClientID%>"),
          document.getElementById("<%=anotherHiddenCtrl.ClientID%>")];
}
```

... and then in your parent page, something like:

```
var frame = document.getElementById('myIFrame');
var ctrls = frame.document.getCtrls();
for(var i=0;i<ctrls.length;i++){
  ctrls[i].value = "New Value";
}
```

They're just ideas on a general theme

Comment: This. Is. Awesome! Great functionality options. :D Will try them immediately.

Comment: @John, did you manage to get it all sorted? Please remember were here to try and help, but we do appreciate being rewarded when necessary (hint, hint) ;-)